# ADFS 3.0 + Cordova Mobile App +API

Tags: cordova, adfs, adal

Our Cordova app needs to request security tokens from an on-premise ADFS (3.0). Then use the token to connect to web services. All the examples I found say this is possible but only demonstrate how to do so using Azure.

Where can I find detailed information for configuring ADFS 3.0? Does a better approach exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem today. Here's the working example. It should work for all mobile apps, not just Cordova.

```
        string adfsHost = "https://<Your ADFS FQDN>";
        string sendTo = $"{adfsHost}/adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed";
        string _username = "<Your Domain\\<Your username>"; 
        string _password = "<Your password>";
        string applyTo = "<Your Resource URI>";
        string tokenType = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:jwt";

        string soapMessage = $@"
            <s:Envelope xmlns:s=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope""
                        xmlns:a=""http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing""
                        xmlns:u=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"">
              <s:Header>
                <a:Action s:mustUnderstand=""1"">http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue</a:Action>
                <a:To s:mustUnderstand=""1"">{sendTo}</a:To>
                <o:Security s:mustUnderstand=""1"" xmlns:o=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"">
                  <o:UsernameToken u:Id="" uuid-00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000-0"">
                    <o:Username>{_username}</o:Username>
                    <o:Password Type=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText"">{_password}</o:Password>
                  </o:UsernameToken>
                </o:Security>
              </s:Header>
              <s:Body>
                <trust:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:trust=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512"">
                  <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"">
                    <a:EndpointReference>
                      <a:Address>{applyTo}</a:Address>
                    </a:EndpointReference>
                  </wsp:AppliesTo>
                  <trust:KeyType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Bearer</trust:KeyType>
                  <trust:RequestType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Issue</trust:RequestType>
                  <trust:TokenType>{tokenType}</trust:TokenType>
                </trust:RequestSecurityToken>
              </s:Body>
            </s:Envelope>
        ";

        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(soapMessage);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(sendTo);

        request.ContentType = "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Accept = "application/json";

        var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
        xml.Save(stream);

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        string strResponse;
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII))
            {
                strResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        XmlDocument xml2 = new XmlDocument();
        xml2.LoadXml(strResponse);

        XmlNode node = xml2.SelectSingleNode("//*[@ValueType='urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:jwt']");
        XmlReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(node);
        JwtSecurityToken token = (JwtSecurityToken)handler.ReadToken(reader);

        string encryptedToken = token.RawData;
```

The code simulates receiving user credentials from a mobile app at the top. Then it setups up the rest of the values necessary to call ADFS 3.0. The values are inserted into the SOAP envelope using string interpolation.

Next, it creates a web request. Then it adds the SOAP envelope to the request and calls the ADFS endpoint. You should receive a SOAP response containing a BinarySecurityToken and a status code 200.

The JWT token is wrapped inside the BinarySecurityToken. To get it out, you must select the wsse:BinarySecurityToken which contains it and use JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken() to pull it out. Then you can send the token to the mobile app where it can be used to complete API requests.

You could use the same approach to call ADFS directly from the mobile phone also but I prefer doing it on the API side.

Also, I strongly advise you NOT to use self-signed certificates. IMHO, many of the ADFS interactions simply won't work. Just save yourself the headache.